# What does cd - (cd hyphen) do?

Tags: command-line, cd-command

I typed `cd -` in terminal by mistake today, and I got an error saying:

```
bash: cd: OLDPWD not set
```

And unfortunately, `man cd` doesn't exist.

```
No manual entry for cd
```

What does it actually do?

Comment: `cd` is a Bash builtin. It is therefore documented in [`man bash-builtins`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man7/bash-builtins.7.html#contenttoc20), instead of its own page. This holds true for all other Bash builtins. You can tell it's a builtin because of the `bash: ` in front of the error message.

Comment: `help cd` does work for builtin commands, but unfortunately it doesn't say anything about the `-` special name. `man bash-builtins` mentioned above however does :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`cd -` switches between the old and new present working directories.

```bsh
avinash@avinash:~$ cd -
bash: cd: OLDPWD not set
avinash@avinash:~$ cd ~/Desktop
avinash@avinash:~/Desktop$ pwd
/home/avinash/Desktop
avinash@avinash:~/Desktop$ cd -
/home/avinash
avinash@avinash:~$
```

See also,

```bsh
avinash@avinash:~$ echo $OLDPWD

avinash@avinash:~$ cd ~/Desktop
avinash@avinash:~/Desktop$ echo $OLDPWD
/home/avinash
avinash@avinash:~/Desktop$ cd d
avinash@avinash:~/Desktop/d$ echo $OLDPWD
/home/avinash/Desktop
avinash@avinash:~/Desktop/d$
```

The `$OLDPWD` variable stores the path of the previous present working directory.

Answer (score 10):

Avinash Raj's answer is completely correct but as for the manual entry, you can get the POSIX manual pages and then `man cd` will work:

```
sudo apt-get install manpages-posix
man cd
```

The bit that tells you all this is the OPERANDS section:

```
-      When a hyphen is used as the operand, this shall be equivalent to the command:

       cd "$OLDPWD" && pwd

which changes to the previous working directory and then writes its name.
```